# Amending a separate tax return to a joint return

Tags: united-states, income-tax, amended-tax-return

I am a non-resident, independent contractor, married to a US citizen and have filed my 1040-ES and 540-ES with my own information, leaving our my wife's details (which I gather is only required if I intended to file jointly?)

For 2012, I also intend to file the 1040 and 540 as married filing separately (and possibly so for the next 3 years).

This is because I am a non-resident for tax purposes and do not need to pay FICA if filing married filing separately.

However, if I ever find out, by 2015 (3 years from now) that it would have been beneficial for my family had I filed "married filing jointly", can I amend the tax returns for 2012, 2013 and 2014 and:

1. file change in status from "married filing separately" to "married filing jointly"
2. pay the FICA contributions that would have are now due otherwise (since I would have needed to contribute to FICA if "married filing jointly" versus not needing to do so, as I elect now, when filing as "married filing separately")

This resource might be useful regarding the 3 year amendment rule, specifically "(b) Joint return after filing separate return" : http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/6013

Comment: Selective reading again? What about 6013(a)(1) "no joint return shall be made if either the husband or wife at any time during the taxable year is a nonresident alien" and the very beginning of 6013(b) which restricts the applicability of the rule to those who have "... filed a separate return for a taxable year for which a joint return **could** have been made by him and his spouse under subsection (a)" which restriction you clearly do not meet since (a) specifically prohibits you from filing a joint return with your spouse? You really can't have your (FI)Cake and eat it too.

Comment: "6013(a)(1)" can be avoided by writing a letter to the IRS with both spouses choosing to make an election: http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Nonresident-Spouse-Treated-as-a-Resident
Hence, the "could" clause of "6013(b)" applies, as I *could* have been treated as a resident *had* both of us chosen to make the election in 2012. Is my argument valid?

Comment: @sekharan no. Have you read my answer? If you file MFJ you will be relying on a **different** law.

Comment: @littleadv: My question is, if I MFS *now*, can I amend the same tax return(s) to MFJ. While MFJ now would not allow me to change it after April, I have an inkling MFS now can be changed to MFJ within 3 years from now?

Comment: If you _elect_ to be treated as a resident for 2012, then you cannot avoid being _treated_ as a resident and thus liable for FICA taxes, as well as taxes on your worldwide income, and this applies regardless of whether you file MFS or MFJ.  It is _not_ the case that FICA taxes are due on your self-employment income only if you file MFJ after you and your spouse elect to have you treated as a resident. If you have wages, tax must be withheld. If you are self-employed, the FICA taxes (both employee and employer share) are your responsibility to send in via 1040-ES etc.

Comment: @dilip, if he elects to be treated as resident, he doesn't have the option of MFS *at all*. He can only file MFJ. Our OP here is trying to save a couple of nickels, and is too cheap to ask for a professional advice. He said he did, but I don't believe him, these are trivial questions that even I can answer, let alone any decent CPA or EA.

Comment: @littleadv I am not sure that he is _required_ to file MFJ after he and his spouse elect to have him treated as a resident, but I think it is his unshakeable belief that he must pay FICA taxes only if he files MFJ, that MFS filers don't pay FICA taxes. But I agree with your characterization of the OP's behavior.

Comment: @dilip he is required. He can only make the election to be treated as resident in conjunction with MFJ filing under sec. 6013. When he's talking about MFS, he's referring to MFS filing NR, and since he's a F1 OPT, he is in fact exempt from FICA in this case. The concerns are valid, its just his way of gathering and analyzing the info seem to be problematic, IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong subsection. The one that discusses your situation is 26 USC 6013(g) (on the same page you linked). It says explicitly that you cannot revoke the election after the date on which the return is due. If you're filing a joint return - it will be based on 6013(g), not 6013(b).

So if you filed as MFJ, you cannot change it after April 15. The sub-section you talk about (26 USC 6013(b)) doesn't apply to you as you're a non-resident alien for that subsection and cannot file a joint return based on it.

---

You're talking about **retroactively** changing from NR MFS to R MFJ. Retroactive change from MFS to MFJ is authorized **only** by subsection (b).

Reading 6013(b) again, I see this:

> Except as provided in paragraph (2), *if an individual has filed a
>   separate return for a taxable year for which a joint return could have
>   been made by him and his spouse under subsection (a)* and the time
>   prescribed by law for filing the return for such taxable year has
>   expired, such individual and his spouse may nevertheless make a joint
>   return for such taxable year.

I believe in your case the condition

> if an individual has filed a
>   separate return for a taxable year for which a joint return could have
>   been made by him and his spouse **under subsection (a)**

Doesn't hold (as you couldn't have filed under subsection (a), you could only file under subsection (g)).

So I believe you cannot make retroactive election after you've filed a NR return.

Do consult with a professional on it, as I'm not a professional and this is in no way a tax advice.

Comment: I don't follow. I am MFS in 2012 but plan to amend it to MFJ in 2015. I can't locate the explicit clause you mention. Is that '(3) Duration of election'? I *can*, in 2012, and hence *could* have, in 2015, file as resident if filing MFJ. Hence, the "could" clause of "6013(b)" applies, as I *could* have been treated as a resident *had* both of us chosen to make the election in 2012. Is my argument valid?

Comment: @sekharan you're talking about amending from MFJ to MFS or from MFS to MFJ? I'm confused.

Comment: talking about amending from MFS to MFJ

Comment: @sekharan see my revised answer. My previous comment seems to be incorrect on the issue.

Comment: You are correct about the retroactive part. My question was simple: Can I file MFJ later? If yes, can I then pay the FICA that is due (since I do not need to pay FICA when filing MFS). Assuming subsection (a) held true for me, if I chose to amend my returns to MFJ later, would I be able to pay the FICA that would have been due otherwise? Also, should I be looking for a Tax attorney or a CPA/EA? I have been meeting CPAs so far and they charge by the hour with no free initial consultations.

Comment: If you agree with me that I'm correct about the retroactive part, what is unclear to you? No, you cannot retroactively change from MFS to MFJ if you were non-resident when you filed MFS (even if you could use 6013(g) at that time to file MFJ). Subsection a is **not** true for you, why would we assume otherwise? Had it been true for you, the question of whether to pay FICA or not wouldn't be relevant at all. I see no reason why would you need an attorney. Find CPA's that provide initial consultations for free, there are plenty of those. Usually the better ones.

Answer (score 3):

As a nonresident alien, you *cannot* file a joint return with your US citizen spouse; your tax status is MFS.  **But**, with the consent of your spouse, you can *elect* to be treated 
as a US citizen/resident for tax purposes, and you can file a joint return with your
spouse should it be your joint pleasure to do so. This **election** makes you liable to pay
Social Security and Medicare taxes on your *earned* income; it doesn't matter diddly-squat
that you are filing MFS after making the election to be treated as a resident
or that you had some wages in early 2012 on which no Social Security or Medicare
taxes were withheld because you were unmarried at that time and were a nonresident
alien or that your **visa** status continues to be that of nonresident alien. Your 
**tax**
status is that of a resident once you and your spouse tell the IRS that you want
to be treated as a resident alien for tax purposes, and you are liable
for FICA taxes on all your earned income.

What you want to do is

- make an election to be treated as a resident for **tax** purposes
- file an MFS return and not pay any FICA taxes on the grounds that your **visa**
  status is that of nonresident alien
- have the option of amending your return from MFS to MFJ at a later date because
  you have suddenly decided that it is more advantageous to do so, and pay the
  FICA taxes then because you are now filing MFJ

The middle item is something you **cannot** do once you have *elected*
to be treated as a resident for tax purposes. You do **not** get to
file a nonresident tax return or avoid paying FICA taxes on the grounds
that nonresident aliens (which is what the stamp in your passport says
you are) are not liable for FICA tax.  Nor do you get to use any part
of the US-India Tax Treaty rules that apply to Indian citizens who
have nonresident status in the US; you forfeit that right when you
elect to be taxed as a US resident.  The first part of the
third item above is something that you *could* do, but it will make
no difference as far as your FICA taxes for 2012 are concerned -- 
they are due by April 15, 2013 regardless of whether you file MFS
or MFJ after electing to be treated as a resident-- only income
taxes due might (possibly) change.

I will also recommend to your spouse that she become familiar with
the *innocent spouse* part of the IRS regulations if she files a
joint tax return with you.

Comment: For 2012, I *dont* want to do #1, but #2 yes. #3 not applicable now. In 2015, I **do* want to do #1, #2 N/A, #3 becomes the question I am seeking an answer to

Comment: There is no point in continuing this discussion. Since you dislike hearing what littleadv and I have tried to explain to you, you should file your income tax returns in accordance with _your_ understanding of the tax laws, and the IRS will determine if your returns are in accordance with _its_ understanding of the tax laws. I wish you all the best in your endeavours.

Comment: There is nothing to dislike about either answers. Facts remain true, whether I dislike it or not. I am having issues understanding details and need help. Prfessionals are not interested in me because they earn the same consulting fees doing less work. Most are not aware about NR laws either, and are not interested. The points under your "What you want to do is" is incorrect, and I tried to tell you what I *really* wanted to do. My question was simple: Can I file MFJ later? If yes, can I then pay the FICA that is due (since I do not need to pay FICA when filing MFS). Thank you for your time.